# Count all the entity between periods - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to count all the entities that created between August 1 until May 31 for each year. (academic year)

I am successful counting it monthly, but it's not good enough:

```
SELECT
    CAST(MONTH(en.CreatedDate) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-' + CAST(YEAR(en.CreatedDate) AS VARCHAR(4)),
    COUNT(*) NumberOfEvent
FROM
    Entity en
INNER JOIN
    Event e ON e.EntityId = en.EntityId
GROUP BY
    CAST(MONTH(en.CreatedDate) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-' + CAST(YEAR(en.CreatedDate) AS VARCHAR(4))
```

Can someone help me with this?
Thanks.

Comment: I don't follow what you're actually after here. If you want a single count of rows between to dates, then you need to add a `WHERE` to filter your data to those dates.

Comment: Try `WHERE NOT (MONTH(en.CreatedDate) BETWEEN 6 AND 8) GROUP BY EMONTH(en.CreatedDate)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this :

```
select Case when MONTH(en.CreatedDate) < 6 Then CAST(YEAR(en.CreatedDate) - 1 AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-' + CAST(YEAR(en.CreatedDate) AS VARCHAR(4))
       Else CAST(YEAR(en.CreatedDate) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-' + CAST(YEAR(en.CreatedDate) + 1 AS VARCHAR(4)),
       count(*) NumberOfEvent
From Entity en
Inner Join Event e on e.EntityId = en.EntityId
Group By Case when MONTH(en.CreatedDate) < 6 Then CAST(YEAR(en.CreatedDate) - 1 AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-' + CAST(YEAR(en.CreatedDate) AS VARCHAR(4))
         Else CAST(YEAR(en.CreatedDate) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-' + CAST(YEAR(en.CreatedDate) + 1 AS VARCHAR(4))
```

Explanation :
when the month is small than 6 then it's part of (year - 1) and year, else it's part of year and (year + 1)

and to make sure that data of month 6 and 7 is not calculated in case there is wrong data in the database you can add this condition:

```
Where Month(en.CreatedDate) < 6 and Month(en.CreatedDate) > 7
```